# IActionResult parameter not being passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, parameter-passing, ngrok

I am POSTing the following request to

`http://somesite.ngrok.io/nexmo?to=61295543680&from=68889004478&conversation_uuid=CON-btt4eba4-dbc3-4019-a978-ef3b230e923a&uuid=2ddh8172jbc252e02fa0e99445811fdc`

The action controller method in my ASP.NET Core application is:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(string uuid)
{
    string s = uuid;
    return View();
}
```

When setting a breakpoint at the `return` line, why does `s = null`? It should equal `2ddh8172jbc252e02fa0e99445811fdc`.

**UPDATE**

Adding `[FromQuery]` doesn't seem to be working. I contacted the API team and they got back to me saying that this is the information they were POSTing to my url:

```
"HTTP-METHOD=POST"
"HTTP-RESP=callback response is ignored"
"CONVERSATION-ID=CON-81593cc2-cba0-49e7-8283-f08813e1a98e"
"HTTP-REQ={from=61400104478, to=61290567680, uuid=8a4079c012c1bfa23f6dff8485e27d00, conversation_uuid=CON-81593cc2-cba0-49e7-8283-f08813e1a98e, status=started, direction=inbound, timestamp=2018-08-31T15:05:02.729Z}"
```

Is there anything from this information that helps? Maybe I have to deserialise something? I wouldn't have thought so but I don't understand why I am not retrieving the `uuid` value, and I can see the request has actually made it to my controller action...

Comment: Because you did not tell the action to expect the parameter from the URI

Comment: You should never POST with a query string anyways. The query string is part of the URI, and should be idempotent, whereas a POST is by nature *not*. You have a request body with a POST - use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you did not tell the action to expect the parameter from the query string

> `[FromHeader]`, `[FromQuery]`, `[FromRoute]`, `[FromForm]`: Use these to specify the exact binding source you want to apply.

Create a model to hold the values

```
public class Model {
    public string uuid { get; set; }

    //...other properties
}
```

and update the action to use `[FromQuery]` to bind the model based on key-values provided in the query string

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index([FromQuery]Model model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        var uuid = model.uuid;
        string s = uuid;
        return View();
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Ideally for POST requests you should be taking advantage of the request BODY for more complex types as query string is more limited than the body of the request.

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)